# MongoDB server-side aggregate queries shared between multiple scripts

Tags: php, python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

We have a MongoDB database from which we pull data from different sources, using the aggregate framework.

A python script generates pdf reports, our dashboard plots graphs of data pulled by the php backend. 
These scripts use mostly the same aggregate pipelines, but the code is replicated in python and php.

We would like to make the queries framework-independent, also because we plan to move the backend from php to python, and in general to avoid code replication.

I thought one solution would be to have the queries in a JS file, or somehow store them (on mongo) server side, but I'm not sure whether this is possible or not.

For those who like to refer to MySql, we want something like MySql Views on MongoDB.
Any suggestion?

**EDIT1:**

I'm experimenting with [server-side Javascript](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/server-side-javascript/) but it doesn't seem to be an option as apparently it only allows `$where` and ``mapReduce``` operations. Loading an external Javascript may be an option too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend storing the aggregation pipelines in JSON files and loading them with your scripts. E.g. in Python:

```
import json

import pymongo


pipeline = json.load(open('filename.json'))
collection = pymongo.MongoClient().db.collection
for doc in collection.aggregate(pipeline):
    print(doc)
```

Comment: Brilliant. I guess I could even execute it in db, calling runCommand.

Comment: You mean execute in the mongo shell? Yes, I think so.